# Rules about input stream using parentheses

Tags: bash

I use parentheses to create input data stream (from multiple sources) to the next command. For example:

```
(date; pwd; cat file1.txt) | less
```

which is convenient and works well. But is this an acceptable/standard method? What is the general rule about this way of generating input stream? I cannot find any references to get more details.

Comment: @ilkkachu Seems like a good answer to me.

Comment: ... see also [Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#index-commands_002c-grouping)

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for the tip about making a function. Seems much neater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "acceptable" is often something in the eyes of a reviewer, and opinion-based issues aren't a good fit for SE, but I guess we can consider the alternatives and let everyone take their pick.

---

Grouping the commands in some way is something you have to do to get that to work properly, and using `(...)` there is a straightforward solution.
The other one-liner option is

```
{ date; pwd; cat file1.txt; } | less
```

which is otherwise the same but doesn't involve a subshell (other than whe you get from the pipe anyway, so it might not even make a difference), and the syntax is uglier what with the mandatory spacing and final semicolon. See e.g. Bash's manual for those two: [3.2.5.3 Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#index-commands_002c-grouping).

Of course you could hide the group of commands inside an external script, but having an extra file is inconvenient. Putting the commands in a function might work as good middle ground. Create a function like

```
somestuff() {
    date
    pwd
    cat file1.txt
}
```

and then use `somestuff | less` if that feels better in the context.